# When using a Range, is the type different for each individual cell when looping via for each?

Tags: excel, vba

I have this loop acting on a Range object called rng:

```
For Each r In rng
    orgArray = Split(r.Text, "},{")
        
    For Each orgRow In orgArray
        fieldArray = Split(orgRow, """,""")
        Call parseAndExtract(fieldArray, rng)
        
    Next orgRow
        
Next r
```

And this is the signature for the parseAndExtract sub:

```
Private Sub parseAndExtract(fieldArray() As String, rng As Range)
```

The VBA compiler doesn't complain about this, but when I change `parseAndExtract(fieldArray, rng)` to `parseAndExtract(fieldArray, r)` it gives me the error "ByRef argument type mismatch." Using `TypeName()` on rng and r seems to confirm that both are type Range. I will probably change this to pass the current row/column number instead of a Range object, but it's made me very curious. Is the type of r actually not the same as rng?

Comment: How did you declare `r` and `fieldArray` ?   I can't really figure out what you did, so maybe you could show a full "before" Working) and "after" (type mismatch) example?

Comment: [Option Explicit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Language/Reference/User-Interface-Help/option-explicit-statement).  _Tools > Options > Require Variable Declaration_ to add it to the top of any new modules you create.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you change `rng` to `r`, this is a type mismatch error if:

- You not declared explicitly the `r` variable
- You declared it, but the type is not `Range`

The parseAndExtract sub wants a `Range` object.

If in the calling sub the variable is not declared, it is implicitly a `Variant`, which cause the error. If it is declared it must be a `Range` type.

Either declare the `r` variable in the calling sub:

`Dim r as Range`

or change the called sub parameter type:

```
Private Sub parseAndExtract(fieldArray() As String, rng As Variant)
or
Private Sub parseAndExtract(fieldArray() As String, rng)
```

Comment: The obvious variant however is `Private Sub parseAndExtract(fieldArray() As String, ByVal rng As Range)`.